# Draw control like Google chrome

Tags: c#, forms, google-chrome

How do I put a control on the Forms "label area" like google chrome's tabControl?

---

[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [sftcdn.net](https://screenshots.en.sftcdn.net/en/scrn/73000/73632/google-chrome-11-700x410.jpg))</sub>

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this link out, might help you out.
[Close button in tabControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183352/close-button-in-tabcontrol)

Favored solution found here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12323/A-TabControl-with-tab-page-closing-capability