# Adding close button in tabpage tab caption in C# Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, tabpage

I am trying to add close button or 'X' on tabpage panel in tabcontrol and I have successfully done this by reading this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183352/close-button-in-tabcontrol).

The problem is the tabbed page title and X sign is merged together. I discovered that the tabpage title panel is not resizing according to title text.

Here is the code:

```
//This code will render a "x" mark at the end of the Tab caption. 
e.Graphics.DrawString("X", e.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds.Right + 15, e.Bounds.Top + 4);
e.Graphics.DrawString(this.tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index].Text, e.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds.Left+5, e.Bounds.Top + 4);

e.DrawFocusRectangle();
```

The result which comes is here I have changed `e.bounds.right` value but still it's not working.

Comment: It depends on the SizeMode. You may want to add a couple of spaces to the text to enforce room for the X. Or you could use measurestring to pad enough spaces before adding the X to the actual text without drawing it separately. You won't be able to control the looks though this way..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you set the [DrawMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.drawmode(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the Tab Control to [OwnerDrawFixed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c0bb8se1(v=vs.110).aspx). This property is decides whether system or developer painting the captions.

Here is code example that uses [TabSizeMode = Fixed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabsizemode(v=vs.110).aspx) is setting the tab size:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    const int LEADING_SPACE = 12;
    const int CLOSE_SPACE = 15;
    const int CLOSE_AREA = 15;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void tabControl1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        //This code will render a "x" mark at the end of the Tab caption. 
        e.Graphics.DrawString("x", e.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds.Right - CLOSE_AREA, e.Bounds.Top + 4);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(this.tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index].Text, e.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds.Left + LEADING_SPACE, e.Bounds.Top + 4);
        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // get the inital length
        int tabLength = tabControl1.ItemSize.Width;

        // measure the text in each tab and make adjustment to the size
        for (int i = 0; i < this.tabControl1.TabPages.Count; i++)
        {
            TabPage currentPage = tabControl1.TabPages[i];

            int currentTabLength = TextRenderer.MeasureText(currentPage.Text, tabControl1.Font).Width;
            // adjust the length for what text is written
            currentTabLength += LEADING_SPACE + CLOSE_SPACE + CLOSE_AREA;

            if (currentTabLength > tabLength)
            {
                tabLength = currentTabLength;
            }
        }

        // create the new size
        Size newTabSize = new Size(tabLength, tabControl1.ItemSize.Height);
        tabControl1.ItemSize = newTabSize;
    }
}
```

Screen shot of sample code from above:
[image: Tab Size in Action]

Comment: Hi whether any idea there to set color or any graphics  for selected tab ?

Answer (score 8):

To fix merged tabPage.Text with additionally drawed "X" just add:

```
tabControl.Padding = new System.Drawing.Point(21, 3);
```

It will add some extra space to the end of every tabPage